Is it possible to use Langchain for both Agent and Memory?
We would like to combine the Agent functionality to search for information on the Internet using Langchain with the Memory functionality to remember past conversations.
We use AWS for our infrastructure.
We want to store conversation history in DynamoDB with Claude on Bedrock as the interaction destination.
I tried the policy of passing memory to the AgentExecutor but it did not work.
The tried-and-true code is as follows.
import boto3
import json
import os
from langchain import hub
from langchain.agents import create_react_agent
from langchain_community.agent_toolkits.load_tools import load_tools
from langchain_community.chat_message_histories import DynamoDBChatMessageHistory
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain_aws import ChatBedrock
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.exceptions import OutputParserException
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor


# AWS クライアントの設定
session = boto3.Session(region_name='ap-northeast-1')
secrets_client = session.client('secretsmanager')
bedrock_client = session.client(
    service_name='bedrock-runtime',
    region_name='ap-northeast-1',
    endpoint_url='https://bedrock-runtime.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
)


# LangChain API キーの取得
def get_langchain_api_key(secret_name):
    response = secrets_client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
    secret_string = response['SecretString']
    secret_dict = json.loads(secret_string)
    return secret_dict['LANGCHAIN_API_KEY']


api_key = get_langchain_api_key('LANGCHAIN_API_KEY')
os.environ["LANGCHAIN_API_KEY"] = api_key


# セッション ID の設定
session_id = 'unique_session_id_20240827'


# DynamoDB テーブルの設定
table_name = 'ChatHistoryTable'
history = DynamoDBChatMessageHistory(table_name="chat-history-dynamodb",
        session_id=session_id,)


# Bedrock のモデル設定
chat_model = ChatBedrock(model_id='anthropic.claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620-v1:0', client=bedrock_client)


# 必要な変数を含むプロンプトテンプレートの設定
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["input", "tools", "tool_names", "agent_scratchpad"],
    template=(
        "You are a helpful assistant. Use the following tools to answer the user's questions:\n"
        "{tools}\n"
        "Tool names available: {tool_names}\n"
        "Keep track of your conversation using this scratchpad: {agent_scratchpad}\n"
        "User input: {input}\n"
        "Your response should be in the form of 'Action: <action>', followed by 'Action Input: <input>', "
        "and finally 'Response: <response>'.\n"
        "For example, if using a tool, say 'Action: use_tool' followed by 'Action Input: tool_name'."
    )
)


# メモリ設定
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(chat_memory=history)


# ツールのロード
tools = load_tools(["ddg-search", "wikipedia"], llm=chat_model)


# エージェントの初期化
agent = create_react_agent(
    llm=chat_model,
    tools=tools,
    prompt=prompt
)


agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, memory=memory, verbose=True)


# エージェントを実行する関数
def send_message(user_message):
    # メモリにユーザーの入力を追加
    memory.save_context({"input": user_message}, {"output": ""})


    # エージェントの応答を取得
    try:
        # 必要な引数を辞書形式で渡す
        response = agent_executor.invoke({
            "input": user_message,
            "tools": tools,
            "tool_names": [tool.name for tool in tools],
            "agent_scratchpad": memory.load_memory_variables({}).get("agent_scratchpad", ""),
            "chat_history": memory.load_memory_variables({}).get("chat_history", "")
        })
       
        # 応答が AgentAction オブジェクトの場合、その属性を使って応答を処理
        if hasattr(response, 'output'):
            output_text = response.output
        else:
            output_text = str(response)
       
        # 会話履歴にエージェントの応答を追加
        memory.save_context({"input": user_message}, {"output": output_text})
       
        return output_text


    except OutputParserException as e:
        # パースエラーをハンドル
        print(f"Output parsing error: {e}")
    except AttributeError:
        # invoke メソッドがない場合はエラーハンドリング
        print("Error: The agent object is not callable. Check the agent creation method.")
    except Exception as e:
        # その他のエラーをハンドル
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")


    return None


# サンプルの対話
user_message = '私の名前を覚えていますか？'
# user_message = 'こんにちは、私の名前は'
response = send_message(user_message)
if response:
    print(response)
else:
    print("Failed to get a response from the agent.")

